# Why do some programming language API's not support private key passwords?

Tags: tls

Two questions:

I've recently started building a basic Go web-server, and noticed that the API for starting a TLS web-server does not support a symmetrically encrypted private RSA key. The API is included below, and linked [here](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server.ListenAndServeTLS):

```
func (srv *Server) ListenAndServeTLS(certFile, keyFile string) error
```

1)
Given that Go is a new programming language, and written with the benefit of experience, I'm wondering why this is the case. Wouldn't the creators want to encourage the use of encrypted key files, and some pseudo-code pattern like this:

```
var decryptKey = secureNetworkSource.getDecryptionKey();
ListenAndServeTLS(certFile, keyFile, decryptKey);
```

Did I misunderstand the security benefits of using an encrypted private key file, i.e. it's possible that the above pattern would not be any more secure than just having the unencrypted key file on disk.

2) I'm also wondering why many of these server libraries across languages (Java being the other example that comes to mind) so often rely on the certificate being stored locally on the server; for instance, the Go API requires a path to a file. Why not support any bytestream, so that you could acquire a private key from another source and reduce the blast radius of losing the hard drive on a server?

Comment: 1) The benefit of encrypted private keys is relatively small since now you need to pass the password to the server, which on a server typically means storing it. 2) No idea. When I'd design such an API I'd certainly accept some kind of in-memory private key. Perhaps this is just the high level API designed to get you started quickly and there is a lower level API that gives you more flexibility.

Comment: Looking at the [source](http://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go?s=55253:55321#L1843), you should be able to replace it with slightly more complex code that supports multiple certificates and in memory private keys.

Answer (score 3):

Encrypted key files do have some value, but generally the value is limited because the practicality of serving a 24/7 operation dictates that the key must be stored on the filesystem somewhere in unencrypted form.  The alternative of the password being typed in by an administrator each time a server is restarted is terribly impractical and creates risk of the server being down if the password can't be remembered, or the administrator doesn't know it.

Being that Go is a new language, it's naturally going to be feature limited.  Not supporting encrypted key files seems a natural omission on a new webserver.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me if **Java** is part of your question or not.

The **Java Crypto API** can load a keystore from **any input stream** (and store a new/modified one to any output stream), but many applications and libraries (and the `keytool` utility) only support files. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739103/keystore-file-is-not-found-in-jar-although-present-in-jar . If your code uses the SSL default factory configured with system properties, that's also mostly limited to a file. However many (most?) OS'es support **files that are actually remote** and may even be something that only imitates a file, like Windows SMB, Unix NFS, or Linux FUSE.

Java keystore streams are **always password-encrypted**, although as noted this usually means the password is just put in the server or JRE configuration, which doesn't really add security.

Also **some "providers" have their own data**; JCA can use a **PKCS#11** "hardware" module -- which can be anything from a real hardware module or smartcard to a software library with its own files or database or whatever. Similarly on **Windows** JCA can use the Windows "certificate" (and key) store, which is stored somewhere Microsoft tries to keep well hidden and protected. It's up to each PKCS#11 module whether or when it requires password(s); Windows store implicitly uses the Windows logon.

**Java SSL (JSSE)** itself doesn't require a preexisting store at all; it's happy to let you create a new key in-memory and use that. Of course properly-configured SSL/TLS clients *won't connect* to you using such a key until you send off a CSR to a CA and get back a cert for it, which is typically inconvenient.